# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table SQLSTATE[42S02]: doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

```
error:  "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table"
```

when I run a collection query in my Magento 2 application I get the above message.

The problem is that the table does indeed exist. however, Magento 2 appears to add the name of my 'database'  to the main table name. This is why the query is unable to locate the table.

> If I am correct, it means that I need to remove the automatic creation of a table prefix by Magento

This is the collection query:

```
$accountTypesCollection = $this->_modelConstantAccounttypes->create();
                                    $accountTypesCollection  
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('brandId', 'barclays')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('brandId', array('eq'=>'barclays'))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('suppress', array('nlike' => '1'));
        $accountTypesCollection->addAttributeToSort('priority');
  
echo $accountTypesCollection->getSelect();
```

**This is the full printout of the select query:**

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `constants_account_types` AS `main_table` WHERE (`brandId` = 'barclays') AND (`brandId` = 'barclays') AND (`suppress` NOT LIKE '1') ORDER BY priority ASC
```

when I run this query directly into **MySQL admin** it returns the correct values.

so, I am unclear why Magento adds the name of the database to the query.

this is the full error :

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentotwo.constants_account_types' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `constants_account_types` AS `main_table` WHERE (`brandId` = 'barclays') AND (`brandId` = 'barclays') AND (`suppress` NOT LIKE '1') ORDER BY priority ASC
```

this is my database config file:

```
/<Magento Install Dir>/app/etc/env.php

 'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'magentotwo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

you can see that the table prefix column is left blank.

Comment: According to the error table constants_account_types is not available.

Comment: the table does indeed exist. i am able to run the query direct in mydqlAdmin

Comment: It happens when you create the table without prefix( while your DB tables have prefix), try with a prefix you have used for your DB creation time. Magento adding that prefix to your new table that doesn't have prefix.that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `constants_account_types` table does not exist in `magentotwo` DataBase so either table is not created or the wrong DataBase is configured in Magento.

Comment: the table does exist. so it has to be the wrong Database configuration. How do you think i would go about debugging this

Comment: check `dbname` in `app/etc/env.php` file.

Comment: done. i have edited my original question to show that this is empty-- so, there is no reason why magento should be prefixing the query names with the name of my  database table

Comment: so do you have correct DB and that table is exist in that DB, right?

Comment: yes.the database is correclty configured and the table does indeed exist. i beleive the error is caused beucase magento is incorrectly prefixing my table names with the word : magentotwo

Comment: No, actually when we run any MySQL query it will add current DB name with table. have you tried after flush cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81994/discussion-between-kunj-and-theseeker).